# How to set application to display to open on second monitor through Windows or 3rd party application?

Tags: multiple-monitors, taskbar, display-settings, fullscreen, windows-11

So my main usecase is the following: I would like to see my tray icons, clock and notifications on my second monitor. For this I need my second monitor to be the "main" display in windows. (In Windows 10 you could move the "main" taskbar to the secondary screen for the tray icons and clock so only the notifications did not show on the second screen, this way I made the compromise with the notifications. In Windows 11 however you cannot unlock the taskbars, so the only option is to set the second display as the main display. (or replace the explorer.exe with the Win10 one which I would prefer not to do))
However if I set my second display to be the main display, now all games and other applications want to open on that display. Which is fine, I can move most of the applications back to the other display on which I want them, but some games are harder to move than others. E.g. League of Legends is one of these games. It only wants to go fullscreen on the windows "main" display and even if I wanted to play in windowed mode, it only let's me choose from some preset resolutions in the "main" displays resolution which is annoying as my second monitor is in portrait mode and I do not want to play in a 9:16 window...

So my question is: Is there any way to set "main" display for each and every application seperatly, or is there maybe some 3rd party application that would let me do this? If you can suggest something for Windows 10 which might or might not work on Windows 11 that would also be appriciated as I'm not "locked" into 11, I might as well switch back to Windows 10.

Sidenote: I kind of got League of Legends working on my landscape "not main" display with making it windowed -> dragging to the other window -> setting back to borderless but it needs to be done at every new round which is not very convenient.

Edit: StartAllBack does almost everything for me. The only downside is that this way the notifications still appear on the screen which is selected as main. (I would prefer notifications to show up on my second screen and not on top of my fullscreen applications.)
https://www.startallback.com/

Comment: Note that you only have 10 days for easy and fast switch back to Windows 10.

Comment: Could you elaborate? After using my key in a Windows 11 install after 10 days I can no longer install Windows 10 with the same key? My license turns into a Windows 11 only license?

Comment: You have usually 30 days for a rollback from any upgrade using Windows Update, but with Windows 11 after 10 days it's a longer process.

Answer (score 0):

I am nog aware of any tooling but usually its saved in the user profile or in a settings file of the application. Its not really an answer but it may helps you search in the right direction.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That's a good idea for some games it may be feasible to dig through the config/option files edit and write protect them maybe. Although this would be very inconvenient as I tend to play a lot of different games. For now I'm trying out the trial version of StartAllBack and it does a great job so far. Only the notification popups are a bit annoying but I'm used to that from Windows 10 and I use focus assist for this reason most of the time.